# TTL() function displays null instead of 0 after JOOQ upgrade

Tags: cassandra, jooq, cassandra-3.0, jooq-codegen-maven

**Select statement using TTL:**
EX:

```
SELECT value, ttl(value), last_modified
FROM test.tblTTLINORDERBY
WHERE useruid = ‘userid1' AND direction IN ('out', 'in');
```

**Before the JOOQ upgrade**, if we do not use the TTL value when inserting data and then check the TTL value using a select query, it will display the values as `0`.

**After the JOOQ upgrade(`3.9.1` -> `3.17.x`)**, if we do not use the TTL value when inserting data and then check the TTL value using a select query, it will display the values as `null`.

Are you considering `0` and `null` as equivalent in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

When data is not set to expire, it has a `TTL()` value of `null`. If data previously had a TTL set, it is possible to override/remove the expiry by setting a `TTL` of `0`. This means that `0` and `null` are interchangeable and mean the same thing.

As a bit of background, this has been made consistent in Cassandra 3.10 so it is possible to set the TTL with either `0` or `null` ([CASSANDRA-12216](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12216)). Cheers!